# Keyboard automatically pops up when I visit a page which has a form in it?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, keyboard

I am building a Cordova app using angularJS and some of the screens in the app have login forms. Whenever I navigate to those screens from any other page,the keyboard automatically pops up. I have tried everything but nothing solves it. Right now I have temporarily disabled the form fields by making them read-only.
Please can anyone provide a fix for it? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is it some form you implemented yourself?

Comment: @stephanec I used foundations and ionic to build the forms.

Comment: Can you create a plunker with you code?

Comment: try calling blur() on the field when you go to the view. you might need to wrap the blur in a timeout

Comment: @stephanec It's a simple form with foundation classes added to it, nothing fancy.

Comment: @Ronnie  I have several fields in the form and I cannot call blur() on each of the fields.

Comment: It should only be one field, probably the first, doing it.

Comment: @Ronnie that didn't work. I did this $('input').blur().

Comment: did you wrap it in a timeout? I haven't used cordova, but I've used Titanium and I've had this issue. Calling blur on the field and wrapping it in a timeout solved my problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103898/discussion-between-revant-chandanala-and-ronnie).